# Use list of derived class as list of base class in Python

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a function which takes a list of a base class as argument, and I have a variable which is a list of a derived class. Using this variable as the argument gives mypy error: *Argument 1 to "do_stuff" has incompatible type "List[DerivedClass]"; expected "List[BaseClass]"*.

```py
class BaseClass(TypedDict):
    base_field: str

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    derived_field: str

def do_stuff(data: List[BaseClass]) -> None:
    pass

foo: List[DerivedClass] = [{'base_field': 'foo', 'derived_field': 'bar'}]

do_stuff(foo)
```

If the argument and variable are instead BaseClass and DerivedClass respectively, i.e. not lists, it understands that the variable can be casted implicitly to the base class. But for lists it doesn't work. How can I solve this, preferably other than *#type: ignore*.

Comment: Are you able to remove the type specifier from the do_stuff method?

Comment: Python itself doesn't do static typing. This is a problem with mypy, which is an optional static typechecker for Python. You might want to add this as a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what exactly `do_stuff` is doing, but nine times out of ten the best solution is to use `Sequence` instead of `List`:

```
from typing import Sequence

def do_stuff(data: Sequence[BaseClass]) -> None:
    pass
```

The reason you can't use `List[BaseClass]` here is that `do_stuff` would be allowed to add `BaseClass` instances to `data`, which would in turn break `foo` in the caller.  `Sequence` doesn't imply mutability, so `do_stuff` is not allowed (static-typing-wise) to modify a `Sequence` parameter, which prevents that issue.  (Put differently, `Sequence` is *covariant* and `List` is *invariant*.  Most mutable generics are invariant because of exactly this issue.)

If `do_stuff` does need to mutate `data`, you'll need to rethink the typing -- *should* it be allowed to add a `BaseClass` to it?  If not, maybe `do_stuff` should take a `List[DerivedClass]`.  If so, you need to declare `foo` as a `List[BaseClass]` to account for that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a TypeVar and bound it to BaseClass. In code, that looks like

```py
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseClass)

def do_stuff(data: list[T]) -> None:
    pass
```

this also makes mypy happy